# Jpa/Hibernate partial rollback issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jta

This is an extract code of my Java Bean where I use Jpa/ Hibernate stack.

I want to manually force the rollback of my transaction by throwing an IllegalArgumentException.

When I control data inside the database I found that containers perform only a partial rollback : 
- update statement are rollbacked (line 26)
- insert statement are not rollbacked (line 30)

What is wrong in my code? What must I do in order to rollback the whole transaction?

Thanks in advance.

```
import org.hibernate.FlushMode;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="mydatasource")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void save() {

        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {

            ...

            em.merge(anExistingObject);

            ...

            em.persist(aNewObject);

            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {

            if (session!=null) {
                session.flush();
                session.close();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You appear to use a `Stateless EJB` with a Transaction Scope so the container would handle all the rollback for you: why did you switch to a "manual" mode?